# Excel 2010 -How do I create a validation list from 2 lists and give them tiltles

Tags: excel, validation

How do I create a validation list in excel 2010 from 2 lists and give them tiltles?

For example:

```
Column A:
1 Boys Names
2 Danny
3 Sam
3 Luke


Column B:
1 Girls Names
2 Sarah
3 Ellen
4 Jessica
```

In column C I want to be able to choose "name" from column A+B without any dependencies.
I want to be able to see in the drop down list:

```
Boys Names
-------------------
Danny
Sam
Luke
Girls Names
--------------------
Sarah
Ellen
Jessica
```

I don't want to to be able to choose "Boys Names" and "Girls Names" but only :Danny, Sam, Luke,Sarah, Ellen or Jessica.
Is it possible?

Comment: While someone else could come along with an amazing option I'd've never considered, you may need to consider VBA: a `Worksheet_Change` event that will `.Clear` the `Target` when the `.Value` is either "Boys' Names" or "Girls' Names".  I also doubt you will be able to have Bolded headings in the list.

Comment: I don't want it to be bold. I edited to question so I hope it's clear what I want now...

Comment: Okay - I can understand the formatting issue.  (You can use an HTML comment, `<!-- -->`, or the character code for hyphen, `&#45;` to prevent the automatic "title" formatting if you need a line of hyphens or equals signs)

Answer (score 1):

For a list such as this:

> Boys Names
>   -----------
>   Danny
>   Sam
>   Luke
>
> Girls Names
>   -----------
>   Sarah
>   Ellen
>   Jessica

You can include the following VBA code in the Worksheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Case "Boys Names", "Girls Names", "-----------": 'If the value is one of these options
        Target.Clear 'Blank the cell
    End Select
End Sub
```

You *could* use `If Target.Value="Boys Names" OR Target.Value="Girls Names"OR Target.Value="-----------" Then`, but a `Switch` statement is simpler and tidier.  You may also want to use an `Intersect` to check which cells are being targeted, in case you need any of those values in another part of the Worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, `Worksheet_Change` is probably your best bet for including non-selectable items in your list. But if you're willing to consider an alternative solution, you could include another cell in which you select the gender to display names for. Then, in the data validation dialogue box, you can give a formula to choose the appropriate list, for example:

```
=IF(A1="Male",Names!$A$2:$A$4,Names!$B$2:$B$4)
```

where `Names` is the sheet containing your lists of names, and `A1` contains the desired gender.

Comment: the problem is I can't include another cell. I have to do give all the options...